# Live video streaming with 200 ms latency

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtmp

I am using below sdk for video live streaming.

https://github.com/ant-media/LiveVideoBroadcaster

Server is rtmp based. We send video live stream to the RTMP server and then play video on AMS (Adobe Media Server) player.

Currently we are getting latency value greater than 30 seconds. How can we reduce this latency. We want to achieve 200 ms. Is it possible to do this with above sdk.

If not Please suggest any other android native sdk that can provide live video streaming with ultra low latency value.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The latency is caused by your choice of TCP-based RTMP and by the caching server in the middle. For better results, switch to WebRTC, which is UDP-based. If you have one or few players, you will be better served by streaming to them directly.

If you have many subscribers and/or sophisticated subscription policy, you need a relay server. But even then, the best strategy is to send video via WebRTC to a server that can convert it to RTMP if necessary. See how [WOWZA](https://www.wowza.com/blog/using-webrtc-as-a-replacement-for-rtmp) and [flashphoner](https://flashphoner.com/webrtc-as-rtmp-re-publishing/) address that.

I have used these references to learn the subject:

- [Live streaming video latency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24843533/192373)
- [Oh, latency, thou art a heartless bitch](https://flashphoner.com/oh-webcam-online-broadcasting-latency-thou-art-a-heartless-bitch/)
- [WebRTC vs. RTMP – Which Protocol Should You Choose for Your Live Streaming App?](https://blog.red5pro.com/rtmp-webrtc-which-protocol-live-streaming-app/)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting keyframe interval as 1, generally this is 10. 
Also set Segment Duration as 1, default is 3